# need good design for dynamic templating and transclusion, or ng route for Quiz application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angularjs-routing

I am somewhat new to Angularjs and little confused the approach I need to take for my project. Can any one provide me some pointers?

My requirements are:
I am using Angular Ui-layout. On the right end split area part I would be having 100 buttons, when I click any one of these buttons, I should be able to display a particular type of question in the middle split area. The questions can be of different type like Multiple choice, fill in the blank, etc. In the middle split area whatever may be the question like Multi choice or fill in the blank, etc I need to have few common buttons like Save, Next, Clear the Answer, etc. These butons functionality is common for all types of questions. When I click any one of the buttons (out those 100 in the right split area) it should just display different type of question that is specific to that button in that middle split area. I have gone through articles directives, template, template url, dynamic templates, transclusion, etc. I am thinking whether ng routing will be of better option here instead of going for custom directives? But these are all some what confusing to me, can any one help me for me to stat up my project with good design?

Comment: Are your questions coming from a backend system? Also are your question types predefined - so can you have one template for each question type?

Comment: Yes, questions have backend system and also my question types are predefined - So I can have one template for each question type without any problem.